# The most speediest way to set all the "Bit Array" elements to null

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a bitarray which is 300000 bits in length and filled with boolean values (true & false). I need to set all those bits to null. So, what will be the best way to perform it. I'm focused on speed. So, is it better to perform this via PLINQ or any other parallel threading?

`BitArray.SetAll(vbNull)` will this work? Any other suitable way?

Comment: Setting a value of a bitarray to `vbNull` leaves it as `True`. Setting it to `Nothing` leaves it as `False`. There's no way to set it as `null/nothing`

Comment: Hey Mona, just wanted to know if you've seen my update yet.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use a `List(Of T)`, and also just a single boolean.

It's not the `BitArray` collection that cannot have it's values set to `Nothing`, it's the booleans.

A Boolean value can apparently only be `True` or `False`, so that's where your problem is.

This proves my statement:

```
Dim b As Boolean = Nothing
MessageBox.Show(b.ToString()) 'Shows "False".
```

---

If you really need a boolean list that can be "nulled", you can use a `List(Of T)` (or an array if you prefer) and `Nullable(Of Boolean)`:

Using a `List(Of T)`

```
Dim BitList As New List(Of Nullable(Of Boolean))
```

Using an array:

```
Dim BitList() As Nullable(Of Boolean)
```

---

[Read more about Nullable(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Since this is a BitArray, it doesn't contain any `.clear` method to clear it. "Bit Array" just contains different set of methods than an "Array".

The `Erase BitArray` will just delete the whole array from memory, isn't it? I just want to keep the Bit Array and just to nullify the data.

Comment: @Mona_Huththakda_Manda `.Clear` is a shared method of the `Array`class. Yet this won't work as `BitArray` doesn't inherits from `Array`

Comment: The BitArray perhaps doesn't contain the `.Clear()` method, but you are supposed to use `Array.Clear()`. I tested three methods here, where Erase seems to be the fastest: http://ideone.com/1cu8hc

Comment: But according to MSDN `Erase` is the same as nulling every value: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83zyeke9(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @ Visual Vincent : Thanks, but we are talking about a "BIT Array" NOT just an "Array" those are two different things. Array.clear is for arrays, NOT for "Bit Arrays" ..  specific methods for "Arrays", doesn't apply for "Bit arrays". ;) , I guess there is no way to set it as "null"

Comment: @Mona_Huththakda_Manda : You do realize I updated my answer to work with `BitArray`, right :)? Look at the top of it. (:

Comment: Thanks Visual Vincent for the code. But apparently, `bitarrays` can only hold the values of `"True or False"`. After the execution of the code, all the values turn to `False`, not `null`.

Comment: @Mona_Huththakda_Manda : Got a final answer for you. (Updated my answer)